# ram file for redis mass insertion with ruby?

Tags: ruby, redis, ram

I'd like to insert a massive amount of data coming from a data warehouse into redis, with ruby.

From the [redis-documentation](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) I understood using a file that batches the commands is the proper way to do it.

However I don't want to fetch all the data, write it down on my drive (aka writing down the batch file), just so that it can be further sent to redis.

Is there a way to skip this step ? I though
creating some "memfile" that could be passed to redis, while being stored on ram instead of hard drive could be an answer, but I really don't know wether this exists or not.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is your data actually big enough and are your speed requirements actually demanding enough that just doing this through a pipeline is not fast enough? True, batching the whole thing, or rewriting it in Redis' protocol is faster, but unless your requirements are really extreme, don't waste your time on this. I've pipelined inserts of millions of HSETs that took seconds. At least try this before you waste time building something you may not need.
2. Do you absolutely need to do this in Ruby? If your requirements really are so extreme that a simple pipeline won't be fast enough, try just piping from a stream of your data to `redis-cli --pipe`. This would look something like: `sh getDataFromServer.sh | redis-cli --pipe`, and would not require you writing your huge file to disk (though it would likely be faster if you did, since the above will depend on your network speed).

TL;DR; Don't do optimizations you don't need. If you can get away for the foreseeable future with just pipelining, **do that**. If you need slightly more speed for the foreseeable future, do just enough for that. **Don't write Redis protocol or write Redis to disk unless you actually need to.**